# Find a volume of a figure defined with: $y=zx, y\geq 0, x=z, x=z^3$

Tags: calculus

Find a volume of a figure defined with: $y=zx, y\geq 0, x=z, x=z^3$.

This is my approach:

First I drew a picture in 3D, and I changed the orientation of coordinates so that $y$-axis is in $z$'s place (up), $z$ is in $x$'s place(left) and $x$ is in $y$'s place(right).

$V=\begin{gather*}
    \iint_D y(x,z) \,dx\,dz=-\frac{1}{16}
\end{gather*}$

Where I saw from the picture that $D$ is $ \{  z \leq x \leq z^3, 0 \leq z \leq 1$

Is this correct since the result is negative? Is there any other way of solving?

Comment: Two mistakes - i) it should be $z^3 \leq x \leq z$. ii) There is volume bound for $-1 \leq x, z \leq 0$ as well. So you just need to multiply your answer by $2$.

Comment: Also note that the condition $y = xz \geq 0$ is also met when both $x, z$ are negative. Just an addition to the previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The region $\mathcal{D}$ in the $xz-$plane bounded by $x=z$ and $x=z^3$ consists of two disjoint regions: $$\mathcal{D}_1=\{x^{1/3}<z<x,-1<x<0\}$$ $$\mathcal{D}_2=\{x<z<x^{1/3},0<x<1\}$$ Notice that $y=xz$ is positive on both $\mathcal{D}_1$ and $\mathcal{D}_2$. Therefore the volume of your solid equals $$\int_{-1}^0 \int _{x^{1/3}}^xxzdzdx+\int_0^1 \int _{x}^{x^{1/3}}xzdzdx=\frac{1}{8}$$

Comment: Understood, it works. Thank You!